# ASP net core API logging via Postsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, postsharp, loupe

I am implementing AOP based logging using Postsharp. I am following https://doc.postsharp.net/add-logging but this does not enlist all information . This is what I have done so far to use Postsharp with loupe *[Loupe is capturing information without any issue , but Postsharp detailed logging is not working]*

```
GlobalASpects.cs

using PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Extensibility;

[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 1, AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Protected | MulticastAttributes.Internal | MulticastAttributes.Public)]
[assembly: Log(AttributePriority = 2, AttributeExclude = true, AttributeTargetMembers = "get_*" )]
```

Program.cs

[image]

Then I have regular TestController with sample code just to test out code .If I look at Loupe it logs some information by default*(which it logs eventhough if i remove postsharp specific code)*

[image]

Question here is how to make it work for ASP.net core webapi or what am I missing for default postsharp logging ?

Comment: Did you set up the backend according to Step 3 of the page you linked? If yes, did you do it before the user's request hit the logged methods?

Comment: Yes i added it in program.cs before host is initiated

Comment: I dont see it in the screenshot. Could you add that code?